# How can I save position of my listview after updated data

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore

My problem is the `listview` goes to top of the page again when I updated data. I want to save post position in `listview`. I can’t use set state btw because `listview` goes to zeroth index but it should go to sixth for example. How can I do that? My code is below:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users')
.doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
.update(
    {
        'begendikleri': begenenler,
    },
);
```

Comment: Add the code for the listview so we see your implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understand very well. What you can do is simply use a Navigator.pop from screen 2 to screen 1 after updating and, on screen 1, use the then to refresh the items.

Example:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2())).then((value) {
   // you can call SetState or your update list method here
   setState(() {
    
   });
});
```